# The width of the bindable layout content inside the collectionView gets collapsed or shrinked after sometime

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We need to show the data as a table. So, we are binding the data as a label with the help of the CollectionView and bindableLayout. The problem is that the width of the data content shrinks or collapses after some time. We are getting the data and the width of the data dynamically from the API, and the data may change at some point.

```
<custom:CustomScrollView
    Grid.Row="1"
    Padding="0"
    Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid
        ColumnSpacing="0"
         RowDefinitions="30,auto"
         RowSpacing="2">
         <----- TABLE HEADER ----->
         <StackLayout
            Grid.Row="0"
            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TableHeaders}"
            Style="{StaticResource TableHeaderLayout}">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Label
                     FontAttributes="Bold"
                     LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                     Text="{Binding Name}"
                     WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" />
               </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
         </StackLayout>
         <---- TABLE CONTENT ---->
         <CollectionView
             Grid.Row="1"
             x:Name="ColumnData"
             ItemsSource="{Binding TableCellDetails}"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
             <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                      <StackLayout
                         x:Name="Item"
                         BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CellDetails}">
                         <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                               <Label
                                   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                                   WidthRequest="{Binding Width}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                         </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                         <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ReceiveDispatchGoods}, Path=BindingContext.SelectedTableItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                         </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                      </StackLayout>
                   </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
             </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="2" />
             </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
         </CollectionView>
    </Grid>
</custom:CustomScrollView>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loxN3.png)

I'm looking for a solution to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrap label with a StackLayout?

Comment: Tried, but the problem still exists @Shaw

Comment: _The problem is that the width of the data content shrinks or collapses after some time._ Do you mean the issue is sporadic?

Comment: Yes, the issue is not reproduced all the time. But it happens after some rendering of this table.

Comment: Have you tried put the table out of the **CustomScrollView** and does this issue happen?

Comment: I tried that. When I put the table out of the ScrollView, the data shrinks for the very first time. When I revert back the changes, the issue happens after some time.

Comment: The orientation of **CustomScrollView** is horizontal. So can the table scroll horizontally?

Comment: And if possible could you please add a image to show the expected result?

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. The expected result is added as an image. What happens is that when we render this table for five or more times, the width of the inside content shrinks automatically for a moment.

Comment: Thanks for response. My suggestion is creating a new default project with much easy and less data to reproduce this issue, does this even happen?

Comment: The issue seems resolved now. I just replaced the CollectionView instead of the inner stack layout. Now the data doesn't shrink. Thanks for the response.